# Circle Indicator in Viewpager in android

Tags: java, android

Im new in android , In my application I am using  circle indicator.but I don know how to add it.. can anyone please tell me how to add circle indicator in my code.Here is my code

```
public class WalkthroughActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int MAX_VIEWS = 5;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new WalkthroughPagerAdapter());
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new WalkthroughPageChangeListener());
    }


    class WalkthroughPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return MAX_VIEWS;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == (View) object;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
            Log.e("walkthrough", "instantiateItem(" + position + ");");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View imageViewContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_pager, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageViewContainer.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.kierkegaarddrop);
                break;

            case 1:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.nature);
                break;

            case 2:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.path);
                break;

            case 3:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.supportlife);
                break;

            case 4:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.willow);
                break;
            }

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageViewContainer, 0);
            return imageViewContainer;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager)container).removeView((View)object);
        }
    }


    class WalkthroughPageChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Here is where you should show change the view of page indicator
            switch(position) {

            case MAX_VIEWS - 1:
                break;

            default:

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

For that you need to download a library from [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

make use of this library in your project like this:
  **In xml:**
how much ever `width` `height` you want:

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="248dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:padding="3dip" />
```

and accordingly use it in java code

Comment: Can we add this as dependency in gradle? (Android Studio)

Comment: Found the answer. Just use the below into build.gradle file
```buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
    }
}```

Comment: how to integrate circularpagerindicator libreary in android studio

Comment: i have coordinatorlayout with view pager i need to show circular indicator on it android studio pleasae

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel - use `ViewPagerIndicator` from [here](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), which will be compatible with your `ViewPager`.

Comment: There no need to use that library just a for a page indicator there are very simple ways to do it by adding images dynamically based on the active fragment in the viewpager.

Comment: It's pretty lightweight, and you can extract the appropriate class. But hey, you're always free to do it yourself.

Comment: error in importing the library..

Comment: That's not helpful...